# setting cookie.domain server side

Tags: cookies, dns, server-side

All,

We currently have a code base accessed by a single domain (mydomain.com) and have a httpCookies section noting the domain as follows :

We're about to introduce other domains (not subdomains) which will access the same code base, and therefore need to support multiple domains. From reading this can't be done via config. But what about in code when creating a cookie.

For example, as part of our auth process, we create a new HttpCookie and add to the Repsonses cookie collection.

At this point I can identify the current domain.

So

```
if (_currentDomain == "www.mydomain.com") 
{   
    cookie.Domain = "mydomain.com" 
} 
else 
{    
    cookie.Domain = "myotherdomain.com" 
}
```

Are there any drawbacks to this? Any problems you can forsee?

Clearly I'll test it, but I'm after community wisdom/experience.

Thanks